# Arithmetic function, sigma

Tags: number-theory

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ satisfying $\sigma(n) = 3n$.

I've tried for a week and didn't know how to start, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Note that such numbers with $\sigma(n)=3n$ are examples of [abundant numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number).
2. There is a formula to compute $\sigma(n)$, given the prime decomposition of $n$.
3. An upper bound must be $n=120$ since $\sigma(120)=3\cdot 120$. Check that there is no smaller one.

Comment: To reach the number 120, since we know that 12 is the smallest abundant number, so we have to start from $2^2\cdot 3$ and adjust the exponent or add new prime $ p^k $ until we obtain $\sigma(n)=3n$, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is the direct way. Lateron one can write this up more theoretically, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, Dietrich Burde.